# RewriteRule for hiding file extension and change file name

Tags: .htaccess, s3-rewrite-rules

starting url - example.com/vid.php
wanted url - example.com/video
any help, pls, to write the `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /vid\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess rules file. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Also make sure that your vid.php file is present alongside with htaccess rules file.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/vid\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ video? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^video/? vid.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a separate `RequestCond` here...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?vid\.php$ /video [QSA,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?video/? /vid.php [QSA,END]
```

Test with a fresh anonymous browser window.

It is a good idea to start out with a `R=302` temporary redirection and only change that to a `R=301` permanent redirection once you are satisfied.